# Rails validation when field change to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a simple blog system.
In my post model I have the boolean :published field: I set this field to true when the post is published.

I want to fire validation when :published is true: my validation have to check the presence of :title (to avoid empty post publication).

I think to use something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true, if: :can_publish?

  def can_publish?
    self.published == true
  end
end
```

Is this syntax ok or there is something simpler to use?

Comment: self.published == true not symbol (:true)

Comment: you can omit the `== true` and the `self.` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you create another method that duplicates already existing (created by `ActiveRecord` itself) accessor? I think this is much simpler:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true, if: :published?
end
```

besides, in Ruby

```
:true != true
```

`:true` is a symbol, while `true` is boolean value.

Comment: I believe :published? should be :published . correct me if i am wrong :)

Comment: @NitinJ you are wrong. :) For boolean columns, `ActiveRecord` creates also attr reader with `?`, to increase readability.

Comment: i am using the same without ? and my field is boolean and its work perfectly because boolean field only returns true or false. i will try to find out the difference between them

Comment: @NitinJ of course, `ActiveRecord` creates also "traditional" attr reader, without `?`. I didn't say it doesn't. Notice the word "also" in my comment. :)
And, BTW, it's no difference. I used `?` version only to improve readability, as I said before.

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :title, presence: true, if: :published
```